# How to convert true type font to bitmap in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bitmap, truetype

I'm trying to take TrueType fonts and convert them to bitmap/PNG fonts for a game. I use Ruby for most of my asset processing.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you can create an HTML page that just displays each letter of a font, send that to a headless webdriver like Selenium, and capture the screenshot, then you can probably do it. And it would not be so hard to automate that for each letter you want.

Comment: This would be pretty straightforward with RMagick or MiniMagick and [ImageMagick's text drawing features](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/).

Comment: @Jordan Thanks; that may work.  After more digging it looks like it may also be possible using gosu + devil which also might be a good fit.  I'm doing some other image processing already with with RMagick though.  I didn't realize it also works with fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will want to use canvas for that. CreateJS library will help you a lot with this. It has a built-in function for that:

http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/BitmapText.html

Comment: This is a JavaScript solution; I'm looking for a way to do this within Ruby. Also; that doesn't look like it does what I am asking.  That appears to just display bitmap fonts.  I'm trying to parse true type/open type fonts and then regenerate my own custom bitmap font files from it.

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby Bitmap Fonts](https://github.com/iblue/ruby-bitmap-fonts) is a BDF (Glyph Bitmap Distribution Format) renderer for Ruby, and able to generate a bitmap for fonts specified in BDF. It's available as a [Ruby Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-bitmap-fonts) too. Other libraries or tools will be able to convert font specifications to BDF.